# Excel VBA - Calling Stored Procedure Timeout after x executions

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

Can someone explain me this behaviour?

We are executing a stored procedure calling it from Excel VBA and placing the results in a pivot table. We use this code:

```
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

connectionstring = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=***;User ID=***;Initial Catalog=***;Data Source=***"
cnn.Open connectionstring

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .commandText = "EXEC spTest '" xxx "', '" & xxx "';"
End With

Set rst = cmd.Execute
```

The stored procedure: contains 200 lines of code that executes in 1 sec with the correct result.

The problem occurs after x time of successfull executions that we get a timeout error. The only way I can slove this problem, is to comment out 75% of the stored procedure and execute it again from Excel. Next we comment out 50% of the stored procedure and execute it again. Next 25% and the last run we execute the full stored procedure again and now there is no more timeout error coming out.

When I call it now it returns the results in about 3 seconds in a pivot table in Excel. This is not the first time I ran into this problem.

Does anyone else ever had this issue? What can I do about it? What causes this behaviour?

Thx!

Comment: Post the stored procedure code.

Comment: Hi, I think I've found the issue. We've added the WITH RECOMPILE hint to the stoed procedure. It was a Parameter Sniffing issue. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have quires which take more than 30 secs, that is the default timeout for the  command.

try changing this

```
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .commandText = "EXEC spTest '" xxx "', '" & xxx "';"
End With
```

to

```
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandTimeout = 1200
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .commandText = "EXEC spTest '" xxx "', '" & xxx "';"
End With
```

this will set your timeout to 1200 seconds , This should hopefully solve it.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this already before asking this question here. This didn't work. But thx